# Android ListView not scaling properly

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-scrollview

I am new to android programming and I came across a problem I can not solve. I googled it for a while but did not find the sollution to my scenario. Far as I understand ListViews in android are adopting their size based on the space on the screen, but what if I need more space.

I have a layout like below on picture and problem is that second ListView is only one item big and then you need to scroll, but I want it to be at least few (visible - non scroll) items. I do not want it to make fixed height. But even if I do then still it goes out of the visible area, which forces me to make a ScrollView which again does not work with ListViews.

So I am quite lost. Please for guidance

[image]

Comment: Offtopic: Top "Back" button is against all android design patterns.

Comment: its just a wireframe cmon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put both listviews with weights into a LinearLayout.
See second picture: http://android4beginners.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/android_studio_linear_layout_example.png

All you need to do is set the weights of the listviews according to the design you were looking for.

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_rel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2.0" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/child_one"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:background="#0000FF" >
    </ListView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/child_two"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:background="#00FF00" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: But what if I want to be scrollable at the same time. Let's say my screen is not big anough and I want it to be scrollable with this two tables on it. Will it work?

Comment: It is possible but with a lot of hassle: You will need to put the LinearLayout-Container into a ScrollView.
Then you will have to intercept the move event for each ListView in case you are at the bottom/top of the List and redirect it to the ScrollView. This way you will have somewhat the behavior that you would expect: when scrolled to the last/first element, the container will instead move.

Comment: How could this be? I am new to android and I love it, but it has some really weird tricks. How about if I make list views not scrollable can I then add them in Scroll View? If I understand right the only problem with ListView and ScrollView is the scroll event riht?

Comment: Yes its the question which View will handle the event.
You can put them into eachother as often as you wish, but at some point you will have to decide which view will handle the touch event.